# Link to nested route from other module in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

When i want to link to other component.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Benchmarking', ['Overview', {'groupId': group.id}]]>Link to other component with nested route</a>
```

I got an error.

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Component "PanelApp" has no route named "Overview". in [['/Benchmarking', ['Overview', {'groupId': group.id}]]
```